# sharing data between multiple processes does not perform sharing behavior in python for windows

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am trying to share some data between some different processes, and I was following the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) python documentation.

In this section, [shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#sharing-state-between-processes), I start with the following code they have provide to illustrate how sharing data between process looks like

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

according to the documentation, the output should be:

```
3.1415927
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

but, when I ran this code I got a different results:

```
0.0
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I was testing it on windows 10, python 3.6
Which means that the sharing doesn't work appropriately, I tried to debug to understand what exactly the problem, and I found that `P.start()` doesn't make the calling for the function `f`.

Why it doesn't perform as expected?

**Update:**
I tested the same code in ubuntu and it worked completely fine, which means that the problem was windows, but I do not understand why windows had such a problem

Comment: It is working on my system (Windows, Python 3.7). So it is not a problem of your code (copied it into a file). What system are you using?

Comment: actually, I just tried write now in ubuntu 18 and it worked completely fine,
 but first It was not working in windows and python 3.6

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebook or another interactive python ? In that case, you need to import the function used in the Process : I can write an answer if that is your case

Comment: first I tried spider, then I tried the command prompt for windows and did not work for both of them